# Creating a Text box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen this functionality on multiple websites but not able to implement.
1) I have a text box. 
2) I enter any E Mail ID into it.
3) If E Mail ID is valid ( validation done from database using AJAX) , a new textbox must be create dynamically on next line and this initial textbox must get converted into a non editable textbox with closing button in it. if I click on this closing button, the textbox must be removed.

Please help.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far. If you need a start, look into the jQuery functions .on, .append, and .prop

Comment: If you can see it on a website, you can always click View Source on the page and get the JavaScript/jQuery code directly.  And it's not even stealing!  :)

Comment: read this http://api.jquery.com/append/ . Will give you a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what textboxes you want after ajax success, why not just have them on the hidden on the page, then show them on your ajax success?

HTML

```
<div>
Name:<input type='text' id='name' onblur='checkValidEmail();'/>
</div>
<div id='emailSection'>
Email:<input type='text' id='email'/>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
function checkValidEmail()
{
    //ajax here.  On success, show our textbox
    //since you're not asking about ajax, we will assume success
    $('#emailSection').fadeIn();
}
```

CSS

```
#emailSection
{
display:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t66b6ebL/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can create any html element dynamically using javascript. And it is simple.

**Example**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="txt1" />
    <!-- Here you want to insert a textbox dynamically -->
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var elementString = "<input type="text" name="txt2" />";
$('#container').append(elementString);
```